# Sharepoint Page - Add button for exporting a list on the page to excel

Tags: 2010, export

There was a similar question but all of the answers did not seem to answer the question.  I am using sharepoint 2010 and I have created a Custome Page that includes a webpart of a list from the sharepoint site.  Instead of directing the user to the instructions for exporting a list to excel, I want to add a button by the list, on the page, that will export the list to excel.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

As another option, you can also just put a link on a wiki page or wherever your webpart is, if you want to do it in the browser and not in code:

The link would be 
{siteurl}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={GUID of list}&View={GUID of view}&CacheControl=1

Just fill in your siteurl and the 2 GUIDs. Use the encoded GUID format %7BE4066548%2DFA49%2D4884%2DA666%2DE85A45AFCACF%7D, for example

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about button but you can add a custom action to the list that will do the job for you nicely,

Here's an example code,

```
public void ListToExcelConvertor() 
{ 
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite("SharePointSiteURL")) 
  { 
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    { 
      DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\List Data"); 
      dir.Create(); 

      FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\List Data\ExcelFileName.xls"); 
      StreamWriter streamWriter = file.CreateText(); 

      StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(); 
      HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter); 

      Table tblData = GetListTableControl("SharePointListURL", "SharePointListName"); 
      tblData.RenderControl(htmlTextWriter); 
      streamWriter.Write(stringWriter.ToString()); 

      htmlTextWriter.Close(); 
      streamWriter.Close(); 
      stringWriter.Close(); 
    } 
  } 
}

    private static Table GetListTableControl(string strListURL, string strListName) 
    { 
      Table tblListView = new Table(); 
      tblListView.ID = "_tblListView"; 
      tblListView.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid; 
      tblListView.BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(1); 
      tblListView.BorderColor = Color.Silver; 

      using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strListURL.Trim())) 
      { 
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb()) 
        { 
          SPList list = web.Lists[strListName.Trim()]; 

          SPView wpView = list.Views["All Items"]; 
          wpView.RowLimit = 2147483647; 

          SPQuery query = new SPQuery(wpView); 
          SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query); 

          if (items != null && items.Count > 0) 
          { 
            DataTable tbListViewData = items.GetDataTable(); 
            DataView dvListViewData = tbListViewData.DefaultView; 
            if (dvListViewData != null && dvListViewData.Count > 0) 
            { 
              tblListView.Rows.Add(new TableRow()); 
              tblListView.Rows[0].BackColor = Color.Gainsboro; 
              tblListView.Rows[0].Font.Bold = true;

              for (int i = 0; i < wpView.ViewFields.Count; i++) 
              { 
                tblListView.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell()); 
                tblListView.Rows[0].Cells[i].Text = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(wpView.ViewFields[i].ToString()).Title; 
              } 

              for (int i = 0; i < dvListViewData.Count; i++) 
              { 
                tblListView.Rows.Add(new TableRow());

                for (int j = 0; j < wpView.ViewFields.Count; j++) 
                { 
                  tblListView.Rows[i + 1].Cells.Add(new TableCell()); 

                  if (tbListViewData.Columns.Contains(wpView.ViewFields[j].ToString())) 
                  { 
                    tblListView.Rows[i + 1].Cells[j].Text = dvListViewData[i][wpView.ViewFields[j].ToString()].ToString(); 
                  } 
                } 
              } 
            } 
          } 
        } 
      } 
    }
```

[Source & Export SharePoint List to Excel Spreadsheet Programmatically using C#](http://www.etechplanet.com/blog/export-sharepoint-list-to-excel-spreadsheet-programmatically-using-c.aspx)

[Creating Custom Actions Menu for Specific Lists in SharePoint](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/2013-creating-custom-actions-menu-for-specific.aspx)

[SharePoint 2010: Custom action that executes custom code](http://jasear.wordpress.com/2010/11/21/sharepoint-2010-custom-action-that-executes-custom-code/)